# Writing to serial port on mac OSX 10.9.3 using unistd.h and C

Tags: c, macos, serial-port

im trying to write some bytes to the serial port on mac OSX 10.9.3 with the unistd.h from standard C. I know there is a similar topic, but its 4 years old and there is a different problem, so please excuse me for starting a new thread.

My problem is the write(); function, it always returns with a value of -1. The code for opening my port is as follows:

```c
curByte = 0;
numBytes = 0;
bool blocking = false;
//Settings structure old and new
struct termios newtio;

fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | (blocking ? 0 : O_NDELAY));
if (fd < 0)
{
    return PORT_ERROR;
}
bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));

if (cfsetispeed(&newtio, BDR_ESP3) != 0)
    return PORT_ERROR;
if (cfsetospeed(&newtio, BDR_ESP3) != 0)
    return PORT_ERROR;

newtio.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
newtio.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
newtio.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
newtio.c_cflag |= CS8;
newtio.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

//Hardware control of port
newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = blocking ? 1 : 0; // Read-timout 100ms when blocking
newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
//Acquire new port settings
if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio) != 0)
    puts(strerror(errno));
return OK;
```

I can open the port without problems, but once i try to write a byte to the port with the following method:

```c
{
int res;

if (fd == -1)
    return PORT_ERROR;
    res = write(fd, &u8TxByte, 1);
if (res == -1){
    printf("Error writing to port - %s(%d).\n", strerror(errno), errno);
}
if (res == 1)
    printf("Writing to port succeeded!");
    return OK;

return ERROR;
 }
```

I keep getting error outputs like this:

> Error writing to port - Resource temporarily unavailable(35).

It's driving me nuts! Because the same code actually works on Linux, so where is the difference here to OSX? What does it mean the Resource is temporarily unavailable?

I hope i was describing my problem well enough, and someone can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: 1.) which port/device file are you using?

2.) You are writing to a device opened `O_NONBLOCK` - that means you instructed `write()` to return immediately if the call would block.
The question is now - why would it block?  - see 1.)

Comment: im using "/dev/tty.usbserial-FTVQS67J" as device path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the corresponding `/dev/cu.xxx` device and your program will probably work.

`/dev/tty.xxx` is meant for incoming connections on OS/X and will only work if DCD is asserted.

Comment: I can't test it right now since I'm not in the office anymore, but I'll try it tomorrow. So does this explain why the exact same code is working on Linux with the tty device? Is Linux handling the devices differently?

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! i just tested it, and it really works. what im wondering now is,...why it was working before all the time with the tty device when i was using boost::asio? does boost deal with this issue internally?

Comment: it might also work with the tty.xxx device if you specify `CLOCAL` in your `struct termios` (boost might do that as well). According to docs, this should remove the dependency on modem status lines for the tty device.

Comment: You are right again! It also works with the CLOCAL flag! Thank you so much!